# PHP - NETWORK monitor

Tags: php, http, selenium

**Foreword (optional information)**

I am using selenium with Behat->Mink, to go to a website, make the browser do some things, but after that I want to see the network calls it makes. I've used chrome to see them, with the developer tool -> network. It's very useful as I see some of the calls it makes and it returns JSON data which is a lot easier to use, as all the clickable icons it makes.

**Problem**

So I am trying to get network calls a website makes, for example when you go to google maps you see the calls it makes to obtain "the map". How can I get a list of all the calls it has made when I go to a website? Is there any way with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a way to access the entire network monitor as an object that a website generates. Found this tool for node.js

https://github.com/gregnr/http-network-monitor

Currently PHP does not have a tool to directly access the network monitor object through a CURL HTTP request.